# If same name in database how can solve in autocomplete in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, autocomplete, names, repeat

I am trying to pull out all items which is in my stock database on a textbox by using auto complete. There can be repeat items too.

ex : Item 1, Item 2, Item 3, Item 1(because different brands can have same item)

Here is my auto complete code.

```
            TextBox name = e.Control as TextBox;
            if (name != null)
            {
                name.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
                name.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
                AutoCompleteStringCollection collect = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
                foreach (var s in allStockItems)
                {
                    collect.Add(s.Name);
                }
                name.AutoCompleteCustomSource = collect;
            }
```

Problem: It will suggest like this

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Required to display:

Item 1

Item 1

Item 2

Item 3

Please someone help me to solve it. I know my English is not perfect. Please consider that my mother language is not English.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What purpose will it serve, to have an auto complete box full of duplicates? Add some text to make them unique so the user can know what the difference is, otherwise your user interface will be frustrating to use! People will say they want to buy LEAD, but they will end up with a roll of very heavy metal (chemical symbol: Pb) instead of a rope they can attach to their dog!

Comment: Thanks for the reply..I got what you said. but the problem is some there can be same name different items. think like mouse. mouse can have from hp brand and dell brand. I know we can search it by using model number. but some cases they cant keep remember all model numbers. so they want to search from name..so when they searching by names it should show both mouse. user will pick the one which he wants. thats what my question. hope you got it....

Comment: I got it, but autocomplete isn't meant to be used hat way. You either provide MOUSE and they will pick it, click search, and see all results for MOUSE, or you provide MOUSE - HP and MOUSE - DELL and then they can choose the make as well. There is absolutely no benefit to showing the user a drop down list of MOUSE MOUSE MOUSEMAT ... and when they choose he first MOUSE only show them HP, but when they choose he second MOUSE only show them dell. That would be a horrible, horrible idea. What if there were 100 makes of mouse and the user wants a Logitech? Here, let's do it:

Comment: MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE MOUSE.  Now you pretend to be the user. You want a Logitech mouse. Pick one of the MOUSE above and I'll tell you whether you got the Logitech one

Comment: Please reply to the question. I did not ask that which i am going to do is correct or not. I asked a question how to what i am trying do...if you have no idea how to do it please do not post any stupid thing. let some one to help me who can do it....

Comment: I've replied to the question: I'm telling you that you can't do it - there's a reason why Microsoft didn't allow duplicated entries in their autocomplete list: it's a terrible idea! If you are so convinced you're right, get a job in Microsoft's UX team and go convince them to make a change to allow duplicated entries in the autocomplete list. I think it's more likely that you'll go away, sleep on it, and come to the conclusion that it is how it is for a good reason.. http://www.joelrieves.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/common-sense-just-because-you-can-doesn-t-mean-you-should.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use Brand Name(Or code) after each Item Name.